# Lost data in TCP stream

Tags: c#, java, android, node.js, tcp

I know TCP can't lose packets because It is streamed, however. I'm trying to send (with nodejs) a stream with 5 "52" packets. Format of it should be (1,52,1,52,1,52,1,52,1,52) where 1 is length of the packet.
I'm receiving the same stream both in C# console App on the same PC what server is.
And on android device with Java app in local network.

C# output is:
"1,52,1,52,1,52,1,52,1,52"

But the java output looks like:
"1,52,1,52,52,1,52,1,52"

Nodejs code:

```
b = new Buffer(1);
b.writeInt8(1,0);
this.sock.write(b);
this.sock.write(String.fromCharCode(event)); //event == 52
```

Java code:

```
while(true)
{
  int a = in.read();  //in is an instance of InputStream
  if(a!= -1)Log.v(getTag(),""+a);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what's the problem?
Thanks in advance

/UPDATE:
socket.bytesWritten returns 10 so it's not on the server side.

Comment: What type of object is `sock` (from `this.sock`)?

Comment: It's the socket object received when connection is established with the server from
net.createServer(function(socket))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. That was my bad. Inside java application I've had a lost connection handler which was reading one byte to check if connection is still alive, it was taking it from the stream.